# Can I roll out a new version of an android app without publish after aproval?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

If I already have an app published on play store and I  want to update it, can I send the apk/bundle to review, and after the review to decide when to actually publish it? And when I press like `publish` to be immediately available on store?

Right now, when I upload a new apk it says `review and rollout`, i click rollout and after 2-4 hours the app is directly uploaded in store.

[image: t]

Comment: No. There is a propagation period across all the stores.

Comment: I think that not possible because of all that process handled by google. and there is no another way as far as i know.

Comment: what I want, after the approval period of, let's say, 4 hours, google to announce me that the app is available to publish, and to publish it when I want